Time calculation for Grafana K6 test script before execution
While executing grafana k6 script on the console the time to be taken for test execution is mentioned, but do we have a way to know in advance ie before actually the test begin execution how much time any test going to take.

If you specify the duration option (default null) or the maxDuration scenario option (default '10m'), the test will generally run for the given duration – and will be forcibly stopped if the (max) duration is exceeded. This is the test duration that k6 displays, give or take. The real duration additionally includes starting the k6 process, parsing your JS files, setup/teardown/summary functions, plus the gracefulStop period.
If you don't specify the (max) duration, you must execute your test since k6 cannot possibly predict the future. Why not?
export default function() {
  http.get('https://yourapi/one'); // usually takes 2 seconds
  http.get('https://yourapi/two'); // takes between 1 and 20 seconds
  http.get('https://yourapi/three'); // takes 4 or 40 seconds
  http.get('https://yourapi/four'); // can take up to 1 minute
}

Given the above test function, how long will a single test run take? You can't know and neither can k6. It could be anything between 7 seconds and 2 minutes 2 seconds or more.
And you don't even need to perform remote HTTP requests. Look at the following function:
export default function() {
  if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
    sleep(600);
  } else {
    sleep(10);
  }
}

Does this function take 10 seconds to execute or 10 minutes? What should k6 display as the test duration while executing such a function?

while running the k6 script on the console there is seen a progress bar which shows the estimated time of completion. There is a "k6 inspect" command that works on the k6 script that doesnot have many dependecies. But the problem is k6 script is not consitent with scripts that has dependencies.

@CuriousCoder I don't understand your point. k6 can estimate the remaining duration (based on the last iteration or (weighted?) average of previous iterations), but it cannot give you a precise number. The shows is the max duration for the test. Depending on the active executor, the completion can be executed differently (remaining iterations, estimated time left).

got your point, however there is a command such as -- "k6 inspect test.js --execution-requirements" I see inconsistent behavior when the script has externalised config or dependencies. Have you tried this command?

@CuriousCoder no, I have not run this command. Your question does not mention it. What exactly do you mean with "externalized config"? If you have a question about k6 inspect, then please post a new question specifically about that command (and its actual vs your expected output)
